# Need to add library to my android studio project

Tags: android

I need to add library from https://github.com/romannurik/Android-SwipeToDismiss to my android studio project. I dont know how to do it.

Comment: That is not a library. That is a sample project. You may wish to look at [other projects referring to `dismiss`](http://android-arsenal.com/search?q=dismiss) to see which of them meet your needs, are packaged as an actual library, and have instructions for using the library.

Answer (score 1):

Your given Github [link](https://github.com/romannurik/Android-SwipeToDismiss) is not a library . **It is a project**. But if you need to import `Github project` as library in your project check the answer and post of mine in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30646946/how-to-import-github-non-android-studio-project-as-library-into-android-studio/30650776#30650776) . Hope this helps